# MetaMask RPC error? 'MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.'

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I'm developing the front-end to an application that I'm trying to test. However, MetaMask keeps giving me this error? I tried changing the gas limit like previously suggested and nothing. Any ideas?

Error:
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.

code: -32603
data: {code: -32000, message: "gas required exceeds allowance (30000000) or always failing transaction"}
message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."

Comment: It seems that the transaction reverts (exceeding gas limit by this much is unlikely). Please edit your question and post the Solidity code of the function (and its dependencies such as class variables and other functions) that this transaction calls.

Comment: @PetrHejda thank you for replying. So honestly, I've forked pancakeswap and have been working with that. This is all front-end I've been working on so maybe it has to do with something I changed regarding their code, but I'm not exactly sure what it could be.

Comment: @PetrHejda any ideas on the type of functions I should be looking at specifically?

Comment: I'm assuming the error is going to be in some of the Solidity code that you changed (Pancakeswap is an established project and the probability of their maintainers pushing a faulty code to the repo is low). So in your debugging, you should focus on the code that you changed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to say for sure but you could try:

1. Check any code you changed in the front end, specifically in your code you may have something like this:

```
const contractInstance = new state.web3.eth.Contract(
    MyContract.abi,
    "0x.....",            // contract address
    {
        from: state.accounts[0],
        gasPrice: 1000,
        gas: 100000
    }
);
```

Make sure the gas prices are similar to those, you may have to adjust for your case.

2. Re-compile and redeploy --> for truffle, run `truffle develop` first, then `compile` then `migrate --reset` for local deployment.
3. In Metamask, reset your test account. Metamask > Select Account > Settings > Advanced > Reset account. **Only do this for testing accounts**

Answer (score 0):

Previously it used to happen in older versions due to a gas specification issue which was fixed. rpcErrors.internal` expects a string as the first argument, with arbitrary data being the optional second argument. Passing in a non-
string first argument results in the error being shadowed by an error
from eth-json-rpc-errors.

Please check what you are passing to Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying so many options I have restarted Ganache and re-imported new account from Ganache to Metamask.
I connected this new account with localhost application.

This resoles my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before performing any transaction the sending ETH address must be connected to your own site or UI. So it can get the address of sending account and goes towards the further transaction in the metamask.

**Make sure Your sending account address must be connected to your UI.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).